# Run AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2022 Preview

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-toolkit

Can AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2022 Preview is now available? Need to run toolkit for VS 2022 Preview version.

Comment: From a casual web search, it would appear that it is _not_ currently available.

Answer (score 0):

It is coming with the full features soon I think. But for now: [check it](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/issues/167#issuecomment-952174057)

Comment: Yes, we have got it VS 2022 AWS Toolkit. We want now the ability to publish Python application in Lambda Function.